# why is this not a valid callback

Tags: php, error-handling, callback

I am trying to set a custom error handler, but getting following error

`Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (error::handler) to be a valid callback`

This is where I am calling the `set_error_handler` function

```
    require_once( 'autoloader.php' );
set_error_handler( array( error::class, "handler" ) ); 

class error {

    static public  $allErrors;
    static private $err;

    public static function handler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext ) {
        global $errors;
        if ( $errors == 1 || ( $errors == 2 && $errno == E_WARNING ) ) {
            if ( $errno == E_ERROR || substr( $errstr, 0, 6 ) == 'mysqli' ) {
                ?>
                <div class='errorbox' style='background: #990000;padding: 10px; color: #FFF; font-size: 10px;'><strong><?= $errstr ?></strong><br/><br/>
                FILE: <?= $errfile ?> <br/>
                LINE: <?= $errline ?> <br/><?
                ?>
                <pre>INFO: <?= print_r( $errcontext, true ) ?></pre></div><br/><?
            } else {
                ?><br/><font color='blue'><strong><?= $errstr ?></strong><br/>
                    FILE: <?= $errfile ?> <br/>
                    LINE: <?= $errline ?> <br/></font><br/><?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error class is in another file and I've not copied in the whole class. I've been reading around the web and I appear to be calling the method correctly so I am unsure why I am getting a warning - can anyone explain and tell me how to fix

Comment: are you sure it should be a _static_ method?

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: This code works on php5.6.19 but i had to remove the html inside your handler function, you have an error inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using PHP 7. It introduced a new class named [`Error`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php).

Because this class already exists, your custom class `error` is not auto-loaded. The constant `error::class` resolves to the name of the standard `Error` class but this one does not define any `handler` method, hence the error message.

Use a different name for your error handling class or put it into a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Did you just downvote my answer only to copy it as your own?

Comment: What did I copy from your answer?

Comment: I down-voted your answer because it is wrong. The fatal error is not triggered. If it is triggered the script stops and the warning reported in the question never happens.

Comment: It's not wrong, you're just nitpicking on a detail that could've been edited. In fact - delete the first 2 lines of my answer and it's all your answer says.

Comment: And um ... the warning does appear even in case of the fatal error: https://3v4l.org/3GoDK

Comment: perfect thanks for the help, it's an old inherited code base so namespacing everything might be a good idea. Thanks for the quick response